# Expected no. of friends for a node where every node picks $k$ random nodes as friends out of $N$ nodes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are '$N$' nodes in total. Each node picks '$k$' friends in total.

Suppose $(A,B)$ are friends implies $A$ choose $B$ as one of its friends, $B$ choose $A$ as one of its friends, or both $A$ and $B$ choose each other.

We have to calculate the expected no. of friends for a node.

I have gotten this far -
Let '$q$' be the no. of friends who choose me as their friends who were not my friend already or were not in my $k$ friends list, then

> $${\mathbb{E}[\text{friends}]}=\sum\limits_{q=0}^{N-k-1}(k+q){{N-k-1}\choose {q}}({\frac{k}{N-1})^q}{{(1-\frac {k}{N-1})}^{(N-q-1)}}$$

Correct me If I am wrong . How do I calculate from here on?

Comment: Putting single quotes around variables to italicize them works in Wikipedia but not here. Here you need to use dollar signs to get $\TeX$ formatting; single dollar signs for inline formulas and double dollar signs for displayed equations.

Comment: The user who asked the question and the user who edited it have the same name. If you're the same person and accidentally created two different accounts, you can ask the moderators to merge them for you.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, expectations should be calculated using the [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) whenever possible; this usually requires only a fraction of the effort required to sum over the probability distribution.

A node has $N-1$ potential friends. For each of them, the probability that it isn't a friend is $(1-k/(N-1))^2$. Thus the expected number of friends is

$$
(N-1)\left(1-\left(1-\frac k{N-1}\right)^2\right)=2k-\frac{k^2}{N-1}\;.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This may be correct but you can do it more easily.

E[friends]=k+ (N-k-1) * Pr[Any fixed node x chooses any other fixed node y as friend]  (Using linearity of expectations)

=k+(N-k-1)*(C(N-2,k-1)/C(N-1,k))

=k+(N-k-1)*k/(N-1)

where C(m,n) stands for m choose n

Comment: Please explain what the set-up for the problem is.  Also, what is your question exactly?  Are you asking whether your working is correct, and/or whether there is an easier way?